# Add comment in Resource Compiler script file

Tags: c++, resources

I am generating compiled resources using the Microsoft Resource Compiler as per this link:
[Microsoft Resource Compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381055(v=vs.85).aspx)

In that article it refers to:

```
RC [options] script-file
```

How do I comment out a line in the `script-file`? Something `rem` in a batch file or `//` in a cpp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you can comment out lines in the ".rc" files by using a "//" characters

Comment: You're right! Thought I had tested that but going through my trail of tests, I see I had multiple errors in the .rc file I tested this in (path to resource spelt wrong) and overlooked that the line with // had worked...oops.